# Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using D:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\CIPL1279\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HD:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\CIPL1279\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\CIPL1279\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\CIPL1279\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\CIPL1279\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fstack-protector-all -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\695xx5w3\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\695xx5w3\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -BD:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android.cxx\Debug\695xx5w3\arm64-v8a -GNinja -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DNATIVE_DEBUG=false -DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=70 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DBOOST_VERSION=1_76_0 -DNODE_MODULES_DIR=D:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules -DJS_RUNTIME=hermes -DJS_RUNTIME_DIR=D:\Practice\GmmcoProject\node_modules\react-native\sdks\hermes -DCLIENT_SIDE_BUILD=true -DIS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED=false -DPLAYGROUND_APP_NAME=D:\Practice\GmmcoProject\android\app -DRNVERSION=70}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to reinstall the reanimated version.

1. `npm uninstall react-native-reanimated`
2. `npm install react-native-reanimated@2.9.1`

Comment: This worked for me, but instead of installing that specific version I just installed the version my package.json already had.

Answer (score 0):

i updated my node version. then i added JAVA_HOME to system environment with my java sdk. my react native version 72.6  , react-reanimtead 3.5.4
it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

What worked for me was that I install `react-native-reanimated@2.9.1` exactly as mentioned by @Adriaan. I also deleted my `.gradle` folder inside `./android` folder.

If you're using expo, don't attempt to use `npx expo install react-native-reanimated@2.9.1` expo will attempt to install the right package ignoring the version you specified which is a good thing. But since the version expo installs still produces error. Use `yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.9.1` instead.

**Solution 2:**
If the solution one did not work for you trying this one. Move your project working directory to a shorter directory. For example if you're using `C:\HP User\Documents\Projects\Mobile\Project_name` change it to something shorter like: `C:\Projects\Mobile\Project_name`.

Reasons for this is that NDK has a limited number of path characters. IN one of my projects this was the cause of the issue.

Hope this helps save someone day.

This should work as it worked for me.